# Calculate the difference in azimuth angles between 2 Poses

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore

I have 2 [`Pose`](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/Pose) representing 2 positions of the camera and I want to get the difference between their azimuth angles.
The older pose is retrieved from an anchor set with the older camera pose, so that I shouldn't get errors from updates of ARCore's world understanding.
The newer pose is retrieved from the current frame.

I tried to use this formula from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Quaternion_to_Euler_Angles_Conversion):

```
psi = atan2(
    2*(qw*qz + qx*qy),
    1-2*(qy*qy + qz*qz)
)
```

Then I substract the older angle from the newer, with no success: when I move the phone to modify the pitch angle only, the result I get also varies.

I think it didn't work because it assumes +Z to be the vertical axis, whereas +Y is the vertical axis in ARCore. So I rotated the axes in the formula so that the vertical axis is Y :

```
psi = atan2(
    2*(qw*qy + qz*qx),
    1-2*(qx*qx + qy*qy)
)
```

It still doesn't work, the result still varies when I change the pitch only. Apparently this is not the right transformation to do.

How can I calculate the difference in azimuth angle between the 2 poses of the camera ?

This might actually be a question for Mathematics Stack Exchange, but I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding ARCore or the maths, so here it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following approach to calculate azimuth that always measured in two dimensions:

```
public float getAzimuth(PointF aim) {

    float angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(aim.x - x, aim.y - y));

    // the range of ± 90.0° must be corrected...

    if(angle < 0.0) {
        angle += 360.0;
    }
    return angle;
}
```

...the following approach to calculate a distance:

```
float distance = Math.sqrt((x2 – x1) / 2.0 + 
                           (y2 – y1) / 2.0 + 
                           (z2 – z1) / 2.0);
```

...and the following approach to calculate a plunge:

```
float plunge = Math.asin((z2 – z1) / distance)
```

Comment: Ok, it was actually incredibly simple. I can't explain why I was so convinced I needed to use the quaternions (I actually managed to make it work, but it's certainly much less efficient). I cannot try it right now, but I will probably accept this answer tomorrow after verifying it does work.